# Entity Framework Core: can't delete last added entry

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a problem where I can't delete the last entry added.

These are my classes:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Supervisor? Supervisor { get; set; }  
}

public class Supervisor
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [StringLength(255)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Project>? Projects {get; set;} = new HashSet<Project>();
}
```

The idea is that a `Supervisor` can have multiple projects, and each project has one `Supervisor`.

But when I try to delete the last project added to the database, I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
>
> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'PB.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext'.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

Where `PB.Infrastructure.ApplicationDBContext` is my `DbContext`.

This is my delete method:

```
public async Task<Response> DeleteAsync(int projectID)
{
    var entity = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(projectID);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        return Response.NotFound;
    }

    _context.Projects.Remove(entity);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Response.Deleted;
}
```

The error only happens when I try to delete the last added project, I can delete any other project without any problems. I can even delete the last added project of a supervisor if I add a new project to another supervisor.

I am running .NET version 6.0.101 with Entity Framework Core version 6.0.1 using a SQLite database.

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that you have another classes in your db context too, not only a supervisor.  Or since you created your db  implicitly, Ef could add some columns that you don' t know about. It is always a good idea , to create all columns in your class, not to depend on EF.

Comment: @Serge Thank you, i ended up checking the tables and found out that EF had created a one-to-many relationship instead of a many-to-many relationship in another class, which caused this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change you ProjectModel as below:

```
 public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }  
    public int? SupervisorId {get;set;}
}
```

After editing your `model` add new migration and update your database, I think this would solve your problem.

Comment: This, sadly, did not work.